# Integration of product of functions(Special form)

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Sir, I have been doing a proof related to one research topic. But after a long effort, I got ended up in a messy integration equation. Could you give me some suggestions to solve this equations? (Any method like substitutions etc are welcome). Kind of stucked my work because of this. I am giving you the integration equation as follows

NB :: "*" notation also implies multiplication. Means $a \times b = ab=a*b$

**Given Data in the question**

$   \lambda(t)  =   \left(\sqrt{\left( \frac{t}{2}A- a   \right )^2+\left(   \frac{t }{2}B- b   \right )^2+\left( \frac{t }{2}C- c    \right )^2} \right) \\= \sqrt{ \frac{t^2}{4}(A^2+B^2+C^2)-(Aa+Bb+Cc)t+(a^2+b^2+c^2)  }  \tag 1$

```
 We here imply only positive square root. A,B,C,a,b and c are constants we cant alter the values. Only t is a variable here.
```

2.   $\phi(t)_0=  \frac{sin \left(  \frac{t}{2}\lambda(t) \right)}{ \lambda(t)}*\left( \frac{t }{2}A- a  \right)   \tag2$
                     $\phi(t)_1=  \frac{sin \left(  \frac{t}{2}\lambda(t) \right)}{ \lambda(t)}*\left( \frac{t }{2}B- b  \right)     \tag3$
  $\phi(t)_2=  \frac{sin \left(  \frac{t}{2}\lambda(t) \right)}{ \lambda(t)}*\left( \frac{t }{2}C- c  \right)     \tag2$

***We have two  sets of questions. SET 1 is the original problem. I have added SET 2 as supplementary  because solving this will lead to the solution of SET 1. Any solution to either set 1 or set 2 is welcome. Main issue I face here is the difficulty to take out square root from sin . Note that A,B,C,a,b,c can have any real values. It is not necessary that the $\frac{t^2}{4}(A^2+B^2+C^2)-(Aa+Bb+Cc)t+(a^2+b^2+c^2) $ has equal roots***

**Question**

**SET 1**

1. Is there anyway to solve $  \int \phi(t)_0 cos \left( \frac{t}{2}\lambda(t)\right) \ dt\tag 5$?
2. Is there anyway to solve $  \int \phi(t)_0 \phi(t)_1 \ dt \tag 6$ ?
3. Is there anyway to solve $  \int \phi(t)_1 \phi(t)_2 \ dt \tag 7$  ?

**SET 2**

4. Is there anyway to solve $\displaystyle \int t^2\frac{\sin^2\left(t \sqrt{ at^2+bt+c}\right) }{   at^2+bt+c}  \operatorname{d}t \tag8$?
5. Is there anyway to solve $\displaystyle \int t\frac{\sin^2\left(t \sqrt{ at^2+bt+c}\right) }{   at^2+bt+c } \operatorname{d}t \tag8$?
6. Is there anyway to solve $\displaystyle \int t^2\frac{\sin \left(2\times t\sqrt{ at^2+bt+c}\right) }{   at^2+bt+c } \operatorname dt \tag8$?
7. Is there anyway to solve $\displaystyle  \int t \frac{\sin \left(2\times t\sqrt{ at^2+bt+c}\right) }{ \sqrt{ at^2+bt+c}} \operatorname dt \tag8$?

**Some attempts currently I am trying**

4. Thinking about the possiblity of exponent expression of sin x and cos x  as [here](http://modular.math.washington.edu/edu/winter06/20b/notes/html/node30.html)
5. Thinking about the possibility of  product form results of sin xcos x  as  [here](https://ecourses.ou.edu/cgi-bin/ebook.cgi?doc=&topic=ma&chap_sec=08.2&page=theory)
6. Thinking about substitution method by utilizing property $ax^2+bx+c =a \left(x+ \frac{b}{2a}\right)^2-\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a}$  as done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169912/analytic-expression-for-the-primitive-of-square-root-of-a-quadratic)

NB : So far I couldnot solve it. Main issue here is the square root inside trigonometric terms. It is difficult to convert it in to a solvable propblem

Thanks for taking time to read my doubt. Hope nice suggestions and discussions

Comment: In your 2nd integral, that $ds$ should be $dt$?

Comment: Let $\vec{r}=(A,B,C)$ and $\vec{r}_0=(a,b,c)$. Then we have $\lambda(t)=|\frac{t}{2}\vec{r}-\vec{r}_0|$.

Comment: But how would that solve the hurdle here?

Comment: What is the range of the integration? Only indefinite?

Comment: Yes ..Indefinite