# Matrix Inverse Question- Singular Matrix issue

Tags: matrices, determinant, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

I have a given Matrix equation

$R(s)^{'}_{3\times 3} = \psi(s)_{3\times 3}R(s)\tag 1$

**Conditions**

- R(s) is   orthogonal and determinent 1. Can say   in the format of rotation matrix
- $R^{'}(s)$ derivative w.r.t s,has determinent $0$  . So it cant have inverse

**Question**

- What I need to do is to switch the terms of $R^{'}(s),R(s)$ between L.H.S and R.H.S using their inverse. More precisely I need to make $R(s)^{-1}$ alone on L.H.S. But the issue is  $\left({\frac{\mathrm{d}R(s) }{\mathrm{d} s}} \right )^{-1}$   doest not have an inverse so I am struggling to take that to R.H.S to make a form I desire. How do we do that? Is there anyway to make this $\left({\frac{\mathrm{d}R(s) }{\mathrm{d} s}} \right )$ to a determinent non zero matrix by addition?

Comment: I changed that..

Comment: Can you explain why you want to bring your equation into a different form?

Comment: @Urgje  I was doing one work. So ended up a closed form for $R(s)$. But unfortunately it contains terms that cant be integrated analytically(A form look like this [clickhere](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/929669/integration-of-product-of-functionsspecial-form)). Then I have this relation equation (1) for my problem. Since I am able to find derivative of $R(s)$, I thought it would be helpful by writing terms in equation 1 using integration by parts may end up a formula for $\int R(s) \ ds$